# Do you want advertorials? Because that's how you get advertorials

Tags: support, collectives

Welcome Intel to the growing array of Stack Overflow Collectives™. They've posted two articles, [one being titled](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/intel/articles/69815104/accelerate-your-tensorflow-application-using-the-openvino-integration-with-ten):

> Accelerate your TensorFlow* Application using the OpenVINO™ Integration with TensorFlow*(OVTF)

I think the author used the asterisk (*) throughout the title and body of the article wherever they meant a copyright symbol (©). It is annoying to read, and from the title alone my [sponsored content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sponsored_Content_(South_Park))-senses started tingling like crazy.

Did you know that when the press writes about NVIDIA, NVIDIA wants their company name to be stylized as NVIDIA? And while they're definitely one of the best graphics cards manufacturers out there, would you want a collective article titled:

> Creating cool raytracing effects with NVIDIA® GeForce™ RTX©

It just looks ridiculous. Is this what you want, Stack Overflow? To be widiculed? Is there *any* way to make collective members write articles in the way that you'd encounter, I don't know, just regular Q&A and blog posts? Write like their fellow kids write?

ktnxbye

Comment: I'd rather just not have articles. This is a Q&A site.

Comment: @Kevin no, this is Patrick. I think articles are better than the eventual blog post that the company allows, because the blog posts are generally extremely crappy in quality(as you'd expect from a blog post), and comments are moderated (i.e. almost none get through). At least on articles you can vote and comment freely...

Comment: I mean, do away with the blog too.

Comment: The other article on the Intel collective (https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/intel/articles/69812928/analyze-model-performance-on-remote-targets-with-openvino-deep-learning-workben) is also full of ® and ™. That one is copied from https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/artificial-intelligence/posts/openvino-deep-learning-workbench.html (with a very small amount of rewriting), so I guess the author just left the trademark symbols in after copying the contents. Interestingly that article contains _Python*_ whereas the original on the Intel site is just _Python_.

Comment: Collectives, Teams and Blog maybe could be regrouped in a separate website like advertorials.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @TGrif None of them would survive without the volunteer community to prop it up.

Comment: I would flag that as plagiarism if it was possible to flag articles

Comment: It also has a screenshot of code :(

Comment: @CodeCaster: They do come through (if [enough JavaScript is enabled](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2020/06/24/formatting-wordpress-comments-e-g-on-the-stack-overflow-official-blog/)), but the turnaround time is up to 24 hours (on weekdays), unlike seconds or minutes on Stack Exchange main. That corresponds to having a conversation with someone 24 light hours away (170 AU or 3.5 times the distance to the *planet* Pluto). Thus the low engagement.

Comment: @Peter I've left multiple replies that were received by the site according to F12 but never got published. There's like three comments per post usually, I don't believe that's all that gets posted. Do you?

Comment: The only thing I don't get is what's wrong with stylizing their company name as "NVIDIA". Spelling their name correctly, with correct capitalization, seems perfectly reasonable to me. That's entirely different from useless trademark symbols.

Comment: People still read blogs? I thought everything had gone video at this point. Can you imagine people having to say copyright, trademark, etc... as every third or forth word?

Comment: video is a rather poor format for reference material

Comment: That's not the point. The point is to maximize the number of eyes, the length of time you have the eyes, and the resulting advertising revenue. Actually conveying useful information is a secondary concern.

Comment: @Cody it's just not going to happen for me to write a company name of more than three or four letters in all caps. Also, the company _is_ called Nvidia, the stylization only goes for media and I don't like it.

Comment: I found a blog post and now I'm more confused: https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/11/03/intel-joins-collectives-on-stack-overflow/?cb=1. There's more ® and ™ in there than I can count. Is the name of Collectives really "Collectives™", or is that a joke?

Comment: It is a product, so, yes. I hope you didn't think it was a community tool like SO Docs was meant to be.

Comment: I mean I know about products and trademarks and stuff, it just looks ... Off. I've never seen sites use their trademarks like that because it looks silly.

Comment: Downvote and move on as with any other junk posted here? Not really sure why that thing is still only sitting at -6/+9 TBH.

Comment: Jeez those images (of code no less!) are awful. Sure nvidia of all people can figure out how to make proper images.

Comment: It ought to have been adapted to the format here. E.g., breaking up the (small) walls of text and making sure the screenshots don't require ***extra*** high zoom levels to be readable by less than 20/20 vision (so high that the right-hand panel goes away).

Comment: @Dan - Because in order to downvote the article it requires feedback. So I literally provided feedback on the fact the downvote required feedback. That’s the feedback that they wanted right? :-) I was tempted to just ten instances of “NT”, i also mentioned in my feedback, my original feedback was simply “NT”. Useless copy and paste articles will be downvote and I refuse to provide any meaningful feedback to trash articles like Nvidia and Intel seem to be posting. (This last bit is not directed towards you but whom ever is allowing that trash to be submitted)

Comment: I don't think Nvidia is on SO Collectives yet, but I used them as an example.

Comment: @SecurityHound Yeah, that dialog that pops out is irritating, but IIRC you can just leave it empty and hit "Skip" and the vote still counts.

Comment: @SecurityHound feedback isn't compulsory, there's a "skip" option on the pop up. though it's not exactly prominent (I suspect on purpose). Odd that articles prompt for feedback on downvotes but not mandate it on upvotes, in my opinion. We all know that downvotes are worth far less than upvotes.

Comment: @Larnu - Definitely didn’t see the skip option so I had fun complaining about feedback on voting instead :-)

Comment: We can vote on it and the votes are displayed to everyone. So I don't see the problem, simply down-vote it. It is sitting at -21 votes right now, which by SO standards means extremely low quality. Also when down-voting you can give feedback to the poster. And you can also leave a public comment.

Comment: @Lundin yes, because I wrote a Meta question about it which attracted 500-something views, and a part thereof to the article. Stuff is now manageable because the article output rate for all collectives together is like one every two weeks; I want to know what the company's plans are before we drown in advertorials.

Comment: @CodeCaster Their plan is to earn money. And in case they think they'll earn money by using SO for advertisement purposes, they will advertise here, possibly disguised as technical articles to attract readers. That's not different from any "free" technical magazine really. If you don't like it, then support the non-profit open source alternatives to SO instead. Part of the deal with using this site is that we are subject to the whims of a private company.

Answer (score -3):

Trademark symbols etc. if used excessively clutter content and distract from the information in a text. However, also Stack Overflow itself is using them for example with collectives.

If you feel that the value of content is significantly lowered by repeated not very relevant annotations, downvote and move on. If you give additionally feedback on an article you can do so privately or publicly where publicly has the advantage of immediately knowing if certain feedback has already been given.

Answer (score -29):

There is a [tool for providing feedback on articles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/article-feedback). I recommend submitting this feedback there so the author and editors can review it and make updates if necessary.

Comment: And we would trust them to do this in time out of the goodness of their hearts? Somehow, PR persons like slapping trademarks upon things and writing things awfully, telling them "don't" as a single anonymous user likely doesn't change a thing. That's why it's so great we have community standards, collaborative editing and moderators in Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm not sure "this doesn't belong on the site, please delete it" is going to be actionable feedback for an article writer.  It's easy to filter that out as noise or irrelevant if it comes from some rando in the community.  There needs to be weight from the actual company to make it clear that this is either undesirable or that there are pointed improvements that need to happen.

Comment: But hey - if you're *cool* with us leaving feedback saying that this is inappropriate for the site and you're *cool* with an article writer not taking action on that feedback, then what we've got here is sufficient...

Comment: First of all, to avoid sounding more disgruntled than I actually am: thank you for the work the team does for the public platform. That said, this particular response is far from satisfying - Philippe *promised* us to get things straight with what are the guidelines and, first and foremost, and what are the *goals* of articles as a whole. We expected this to freeze a little during the election and vacation times, but what is *hugely* disheartening is the appearance of two "infomercial" articles (with one containing a plagiarized prefix) in the midst of the promises of good faith. [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] Both articles are painful to see in this light, and so it is even more painful to see a response "file a complaint that might or might not be addressed at the discretion of the one who did this" that I am personally so used to where I live.

Comment: Assuming the author of the article can be bothered -- for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/gitlab/articles/69193717/how-to-use-external-status-checks-for-merge-requests) providing feedback seems about as useful as trying to tell a brick to move itself.