# Does every post on this site have to be a question or answer?

Tags: discussion

I am new to this site and want to know if it has any function other than being strictly question/answer. For example, could someone make a post that is just helpful advice, or do new posts have to be questions only?

Comment: Try going through this https://stackoverflow.com/help. It is a Q/A site.

Comment: "Helpful advice" is one of the components of an answer. All you need to do to provide helpful advice is to not limit yourself to that, but write a complete answer to 
a question. more effort on your part and that is exactly what the site demands of you - that you make the effort.

Answer (score 7):

It is first and foremost a **Q&A** site, as the ["Welcome to Stack Overflow"](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) Tour page indicates:

> Stack Overflow is a **question and answer site** for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to **build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question** about programming.

If you can present or format the problem your helpful advice solves as an [on-topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then there is nothing wrong with posting that helpful advice as a self-answer to your own question.

The site allows and even encourages it, as indicated in the [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) help page:

> If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.

...but do note that it still has to be in a Q&A format, and that the question follows the guidelines for any other type of question (as if someone else asked that question). I recommend to take a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

There is however a recent addition of a concept called [Collectives](https://stackoverflow.com/help/collectives-what-are) which does have a format called "Articles":

> It’s a place for users where they can find any content related to that product/service, both Q&A and content **that goes beyond regular Q&A, such as Articles**.

...but do note that you first have to [become a member of a Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/help/collectives-user-types) and that the allowed content and format of said Articles is under discussions right now. See recent posts such as this: [Community input needed: The rules for collectives articles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413357/community-input-needed-the-rules-for-collectives-articles).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Stackoverflow.com is a Q&A site.

Specifically, it's a Q&A site for *programming questions*.

Look here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Questions like this actually belong on a different site:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Other sites for non-programming questions include:

- https://superuser.com

  About general computing hardware and software.
- https://serverfault.com:

  About professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration

Comment: "Yes" - Well, no, articles are posts that don't fall under the Q&A format.

Answer (score 0):

This is an idea that the site owners may want to work on. But for now, as far as I have experienced it, it is a Q&A site. You can give advice on Quora, Twitter, Dev or Medium etc etc

Comment: Thanks, I'm just trying to understand what exactly is going on here.

Comment: "Dev" = [DEV](https://dev.to/about). Capitalisation matters.