# Plagiarised collectives article

Tags: discussion, support, plagiarism, collectives

The Google Cloud Collective's [Machine Learning Fundamentals article](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/71883132/machine-learningfundamentals) is a copy-paste of [an article](https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-basics-part-1-a36d38c7916) posted elsewhere in 2018, with a few paragraphs removed. You can [see the diff here](https://www.diffchecker.com/DfENaTsF).

I did have a quick check of the author's details just in case it was the same person. Looks like the original author's name is Javaid Nabi, and the [article author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18698772/aditya-dixit)'s name is Aditya Dixit (which matches their name on GitLab, etc).

I tried to flag/close vote the article, but I apparently can't.

What next?

Comment: I'd act surprised but....

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine If I had 1 rep for every time I was right in saying "I told you so"

Comment: Quite a few of us predicted articles as documentation 2.0, with rampant plagiarism for rep. That point has now been proven.

Comment: Re *"I did have a quick check of the author's details just in case it was the same person."*: That may ***not*** be sufficient. The plagiarisers are also getting more clever. First, they plagiarise at [Medium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_(website)) (or other platforms that don't take plagiarism seriously, like [Quora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora) or [DEV](https://dev.to/about)). Second, they copy the content to somewhere else, like Stack Overflow, and claim the content to be their own (implicitly or explicitly). Thus checks for plagiarism become more convoluted.

Comment: [An example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418451/half-the-articles-in-collectives-are-exactly-copied-elsewhere#comment913446_418451) of that is the first example in your follow-up meta post: [Half the articles in collectives are exactly copied elsewhere](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418451/half-the-articles-in-collectives-are-exactly-copied-elsewhere)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In the future, you can bring articles to our attention by flagging any other post (such as one of your own, though any post you don't immediately need to flag will do) for moderator attention, and link to the article, say it's plagiarized, and include the source (i.e. a standard plagiarism flag, but with hacks because SE doesn't like giving us elementary moderation tools to their new, shiny, and easily abusable systems).

I've gone ahead and deleted the article. That said... While I can deal with the article and user, I'm at a loss in general. If the approver  guidelines don't include checking for plagiarism, we're looking at a substantial problem with article plagiarism in the near foreseeable future.

I've also gone ahead and pinged a CM to inform them that article plagiarism is now occurring, and that SE needs to do something about it before we're drowning in plagiarism (again, and more than we already are with standard posts).

Comment: Though, for the record, posting on meta on the first known occurrence of expected or unexpected abuse to a system isn't inherently bad; in general, it gives us a canonical for the problem, and in this case, a very public way to poke SE that this particular expected problem has arrived

Comment: One thing that I noticed with the article was that the approver had under 2k rep. I don't want to blast them, because detecting plagiarism can be a fairly high-effort and time-intensive activity, and I don't think blaming them for overlooking it is constructive. But this user hadn't even got to the point of being able to approve suggested edits.

Comment: ^ in reply to your point about approver guidelines

Comment: Approver guidelines have nothing to do with this specific reviewer; if the guidelines don't include a plagiarism check, one won't occur. We already have a plagiarism check requirement on tag wikis, it's not much of a stretch

Comment: Are the guidelines public?

Comment: I have no clue. Last I heard them mentioned, they sounded private, but now that recognized users can approve articles, I assume they have to be public to some extent. I haven't seen them, though, and I have no idea if I can

Comment: I think low-rep reviewers who haven't spent significant time in the review queues are unlikely to be looking out for plagiarism (assuming it is in the guidelines). It takes some time to get up to speed with SO's standards, it definitely took me a few declined flags and failed review audits to learn what our expectations are. It seems like a mistake to me to give people approver privileges when they haven't yet gained access to the majority of the moderation tools we get as users.

Comment: Regarding the approver guidelines, there is [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/article-guidelines), which says that exact copies shouldn't be posted. There's also [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413357/community-input-needed-the-guidelines-for-collectives-articles) where a call was put out for community input into collectives guidelines, this input was then collated and turned into the help page. I assume that these are the guidelines against which approvers are supposed to review articles.

Comment: Holly... since when Articles went from authorized members can write them, to anyone can jump in? This will be bigger disaster than Documentation.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Couple months, but doing so was the plan from the start, which is why this was a predicted trainwreck.

Comment: Source on my previous comment in case anyone is interested: "Initially, Articles can only be posted by Admins and Recognized Members of a collective, but we’re planning to release a feature (in the near term) that would allow any member of a collective to submit an Article for review." - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408585/6296561. As of [at least-ish March](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/408819/revisions) (non-official source; can't find the announcement, if there was one, but I believe it was a silent help center edit some time in March), that feature was rolled out

Comment: An off-topic conversation about flagging non-Articles for deletion and other moderation topics unrelated to Articles has been [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245246/discussion-on-answer-by-zoe-stands-with-ukraine-plagiarised-collectives-article).  Please keep comments related to *this* answer.  Any future off-topic comments will be removed.