# Half the articles in collectives are exactly copied elsewhere

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, collectives, articles

Further to my earlier post about a⁠—now deleted⁠—[plagiarised collectives article](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418447/plagiarised-collectives-article), there are a number of articles which are exact duplicates of articles posted elsewhere. They all appear to have been re-posted by their original authors. This is in violation of [this guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/article-guidelines):

> - Articles should not be exact duplicates of existing Q&As or articles.

| Collectives Article | Article Posted Elsewhere | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Login to GCP VM Instance without Public IP using Identity-Aware proxy (IAP)](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/72334204/login-to-gcp-vm-instance-without-public-ip-using-identity-aware-proxy-iap) | [Medium article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/login-to-gcp-vm-instance-without-public-ip-31cc01ee152b) | Medium article posted first |
| [Upload Image with Expo and Firebase Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/71629397/upload-image-with-expo-and-firebase-cloud-storage) | [dev.to article](https://dev.to/emmbyiringiro/upload-image-with-expo-and-firebase-cloud-storage-3481) | dev.to article posted first |
| [How to use external status checks for merge requests](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/gitlab/articles/69193717/how-to-use-external-status-checks-for-merge-requests) | [GitLab article](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/10/04/how-to-status-checks/) | Collectives article posted first |
| [Intel Open VKL Library](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/intel/articles/72206664/intel-open-vkl-library) | [Medium article](https://medium.com/@abhishek.nandy81/intel-open-vkl-library-583522539874) | Medium article posted first |
| [How to convert PyTorch model and run it with OpenVINO](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/intel/articles/72141365/how-to-convert-pytorch-model-and-run-it-with-openvino) | [LinkedIn article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-convert-pytorch-model-run-openvino-adrian-boguszewski) | Both articles posted on the same day |
| [Intel® Distribution of OpenVINO™ toolkit --- Optimised Deep Learning – By Tamal Acharya](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/intel/articles/71734589/intel-distribution-of-openvino-toolkit-optimised-deep-learning-by-tamal) | [Medium article](https://medium.com/@tamlacharya/intel-distribution-of-openvino-toolkit-optimised-deep-learning-by-tamal-acharya-6028f3903614) | Medium article posted first |
| [How to use Model Downloader for Encoder Decoder Models using OpenVINO™ toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/intel/articles/71701870/how-to-use-model-downloader-for-encoder-decoder-models-using-openvino-toolkit) | [Intel Community article](https://community.intel.com/t5/Blogs/Tech-Innovation/Artificial-Intelligence-AI/How-to-use-Model-Downloader-for-Encoder-Decoder-Models-using/post/1373694) | Both articles posted on the same day |
| [How to convert TensorFlow model and run it with OpenVINO™](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/intel/articles/71206927/how-to-convert-tensorflow-model-and-run-it-with-openvino) | [LinkedIn article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-convert-tensorflow-model-run-openvino-adrian-boguszewski/) | Collectives article posted first, LinkedIn the day after |
| [How to run OpenVINO with Neural Compute Stick 2 on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/intel/articles/70864843/how-to-run-openvino-with-neural-compute-stick-2-on-linux) | [LinkedIn article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-run-openvino-neural-compute-stick-2-linux-adrian-boguszewski/) | LinkedIn article posted first |

By my count, there are 9 articles in violation of the guideline (although I don't know if it's a violation to post an article on SO, then post elsewhere). I'd guess there's likely to be some issue with licensing, depending on the websites to which the article is posted and in which order.

Anyway, 9 of the 18 current Collectives articles are just re-posts of articles posted elsewhere.

Comment: *"I'd guess there's likely to be some issue with licensing, depending on the websites to which the article is posted and in which order."* This is unlikely to be the case, unless one of the other websites requires an *exclusive* license to the content (Stack Overflow does not have such a requirement).  Generally, authors retain full rights to re-license their contents to others, even after licensing it to one site.

Comment: @RyanM I had a quick look at the terms for Medium, and there aren't any licensing issues there. However, I'm sure some of the blog sites we use to post our articles do require exclusive licenses or at least attribution. In terms of the sites I looked at, I don't think it is the case for any of the articles I looked at but IANAL

Comment: Did you expect anything else from the "in-depth product knowledge that’s only on Collectives", @Joundill? We warned SE multiple times this is exactly what's going to happen, and yet, here we are.

Comment: @OlegValter, annex-Pb is that SO wants to be the ***exclusive*** Source of (Tech-)Knowledge, some Companies / Technology Providers give in, some don't... For the small Tag I answer on this Site, I've already provided/posted a Solution (well "a" = [1 to 36]) for 99% of all Usecases for that ProgLang, but I did that on the Company Product Forum (which existed about 5 years before SO, and will still exist long after SO will have disappeared from Internet, like all "hyped"-Sites, ah-ah...!), then I'm not "too surprised" that 'Collectives' Companies are trying to post some Content already posted...

Comment: Eh, @chivracq, please do forgive me if it sounds a bit unconsiderate, but can you use a more... conventional method of getting the point across? I am honestly struggling with parsing the meaning of the above - are you saying it's to be expected (with which I agree - we all knew this is going to happen) or that this is not a big deal (with which I don't agree because I think it's important to call this "feature" on every occasion where "we told you so" - maybe one day SE will start to listen instead of boldly going where everyone has been before)

Comment: None of those articles are duplicates of Q&A or other Articles (as in the Articles present here on Collectives). The help center also states: "*However, the article does not necessarily need to be (but ideally is) content written exclusively for the collective. That is, repurposed articles would be allowed, but they must be resident on Stack Overflow, in the collective.*" - this seems to indicate that duplications from elsewhere on the web is permissible.

Comment: That said, I admit there's some lack of clarity between "Articles" (the post type on Collectives and Teams) and "articles" (the general concept of a short-form writing about a subject).

Comment: @Catija my reading was that exact copies of articles from elsewhere were not allowed, but that content may be repurposed (i.e. modified) to fit in to a Collective's Articles.

Comment: But yeah, if `"articles" == "Articles™"`, then I guess the guideline I highlighted is irrelevant.

Comment: I'd say this would constitute a violation of goodwill towards the community if that loophole is going to be applied as "oops, we meant Articles", @Catija. It is quite clear that the community agreed with articles being unique content just as any other content on Stack Overflow. We do not allow plagiarism of tag wikis/exceprts even if the source allows free distribution. We also do not allow the same for questions and answers unless the source is provided. I am pretty sure Articles posted on other sites *first* violate CC-BY-SA license, btw. Unless those are prefaced with [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] "originally podted on <link to the article>", I believe they *are* in violation of if not this guideline but the license's terms. We warned the company this is going to happen, and this is no surprise to us, but it does not change the fact that the situation is unacceptable if the company wants the community to accept Collectives and Articles as valid first-class members of the site.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine None of that (license violations or plagiarism issues) is the case if they are posted in both places _by the author_.  As I noted [in my first comment on this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418451/half-the-articles-in-collectives-are-exactly-copied-elsewhere#comment913091_418451), the author has the right to license their content to multiple sites under whatever terms they choose.  Nothing in CC BY-SA forbids that (as long as none of the licenses are _exclusive_).

Comment: Sigh, yes, I guess so, @RyanM. The terms do not, indeed, forbid relicensing, however, I still believe that the attribution clause applies to reposts here *after* they have been posted on the other site in the case the original license is compatible with CC-BY-SA. Obligatory IANAL statement :) The rest still applies, though - the usage of the loophole, if it is technically legal, is still in violation of what the community argeed with when the guidelines were presented (on which I don't think we disagree).

Comment: On the bright side, there's not any other plagiarism at the moment.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine what a foreign concept, to look at things from the bright side on meta :)

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I made sure of that hahaha

Comment: @Gimby Small victories in the field of constant defeat :p

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine The CC BY-SA license only applies if the place where the person obtained the text is licensing it under CC BY-SA (e.g. on SE). In general, the copyright holder requires no license and doesn't need to comply with any license, other than they need to comply with their side of any terms they have already entered into, which for CC BY-SA is that the copyright holder can't grant an *exclusive* license, because there's already a license which can't be revoked.

Comment: So, no, the copyright holder isn't *required* to give attribution to themselves for their own content (exclusive of any modifications made by others on SE). We'd *like* them to mention that they've also posted the content elsewhere, so nobody thinks it's plagiarized, but doing so isn't *required*.

Comment: Euh..., sorry for being a "PITA", but "exactly copied elsewhere" or "exactly copied **from** elsewhere"...?

Comment: @chivracq It's sort of irrelevant, given they're all written by the same authors. Some were posted on multiple platforms at the same time, some were posted elsewhere then copied from those sites to SO

Comment: @RyanM "This is unlikely to be the case, unless..." That is not how law works. Either it is the case or it isn't. Which is what would need to be determined here for every case. Fortunately it's a very low number of cases, so I think it can be done. We just need to read on the TOS of Medium/dev.to/Gitlab/LinkedIn.

Comment: @Trilarion There's a joke that a lawyer's response to every question is "Well, it depends."  In this case, I'm saying that it's *unlikely* that such an exclusivity provision would be included in any blogging service's ToS, as it would be quite unpopular with users in most situations.  I'm certainly unaware of any site that includes one.  It could, of course, be determined with more certainty than "it's unlikely," but I really didn't feel like spending an hour reading terms of service for something that doesn't really affect my life.

Comment: I see the concerns here, but I actually like that the content is also in SO, I prefer the design as I am used to it and I have it centralized here. Maybe rep and voting should be revised in this kind of publications. Maybe copies of other articles should be flagged and their voting removed without further intervention, preventing rep-farming, but still allowing them.

Comment: @RyanM "...that doesn't really affect my life." Neither mine. If somebody gets problems because of it, it will be the company not me. Still I like to discuss things and say what in principle would have to be done to solve this problem.

Comment: @Makyen yeah, upon thinking about it in a bit more level-headed state, I already agreed (and expressed it to RyanM during our chat discussion) that there is no license violation (at least where the author reposting is concerned) - my initial interpretation wasn't correct regarding this point.

Comment: Note that plagiarism is already rampant on [Medium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_(website)) and [DEV](https://dev.to/about) (And [Quora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora). I don't know about [LinkedIn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinkedIn)). No matter what their licenses or terms of service formally state, none of those platforms take plagiarism seriously (exactly ***nothing*** is done when blatant plagiarism is reported). So what looks like self-plagiarism may be actual plagiarism. The content should be checked first for plagiarism at the place with the oldest publication date.

Comment: It is *already* the case for at least one of the examples here. The exact phrase ***"Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP) TCP forwarding to enable administrative access to VM instances that do not have external IP addresses or do not permit direct access over the internet."*** from [a Google Cloud article](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding) was [plagiarised by Vishal Bulbule](https://medium.com/google-cloud/login-to-gcp-vm-instance-without-public-ip-31cc01ee152b) on Medium (the first example listed here).

Comment: With WSO2 joining the Borg, we got 3 more articles that are blatantly copied from elsewhere. While "technically" they pass as "self-plagiarism", they, once again, bring no added value to the Q&A by being simple copy-pasta from external resources: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/wso2/articles/72633806) is copied from [this](https://medium.com/@thivi/magic-link-authentication-using-asgardeo-90438f8d109e); [this](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/wso2/articles/72551229) from [here](https://medium.com/ballerina-techblog/ballerina-integration-programming-language-5d8e1b52e582).

Comment: And, finally, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/wso2/articles/72564747) from [here](https://blog.devgenius.io/building-ballerina-from-sources-948d7db4ee5). Which brings us to 3/5 Articles in the new Collective being copy-pasta content. Well done!

Answer (score 12):

When Zoe pinged me about this (as mentioned [in her answer to the other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418448/4548692)), I checked internally while leaving the comment I did above. Specifically, I talked with Philippe and some of the team working on Collectives. After having those discussions and seeing the feedback here, I've updated the Help Center post with the following goals:

- Disambiguate between "Articles" and "articles" (<s>as well as making sure that "Collectives" was always capitalized</s> rolled this back as it goes against our [guidance](https://stackoverflow.design/brand/copywriting/naming/#collectives-vs.-collectives)).
- Making the bullet point that explains our policy regarding reposting content from elsewhere on the internet more clear rather than having it be a subset of the link-only post policy.
- Encourage reposts to mention and link to the original post.
- Explicitly require that Articles be the original work of the person posting them.
- State that plagiarized posts will be removed and may have consequences.
- Clarify the quoted text in the question - Articles may not be reposts of content on Stack Overflow, whether a Q&A post or another Article.

Because y'all can't see the edit history on the Help Center article, I'll include the major changes below.

#### Explaining reposting content expectations:

In the original text, we used the term "repurposed", which led to some confusion about whether the content could be identical. Philippe clarified that "reposted" was what was intended, so that's been cleared up. I also separated this into its own bullet so that link-only Articles was one bullet and information about reposting content from elsewhere was its own bullet with two sub-bullets, one about linking to the original source and one about the Creative Commons licensing. I also made some minor improvements to the link-only text.

##### Before

> - Link-only articles are not acceptable. If an article contains links, it must have sufficient context, and content must be resident on the collective. However, the article does not necessarily need to be (but ideally is) content written exclusively for the collective. That is, repurposed articles would be allowed, but they must be resident on Stack Overflow, in the collective. It’s also important to recognize that anything posted to our site is licensed under the Creative Commons license as well.

##### After

> - Link-only Articles are not acceptable. If an Article contains links, it must have sufficient context that visiting the links is not necessary, and content must be resident on the collective.
> - An Article does not necessarily need to be (but ideally is) content written exclusively for the collective. Reposting your own content from elsewhere on the internet is allowed, provided it meets the other guidelines.
>
>   - When reposting content from elsewhere, the author is encouraged to mention this fact and link to the original.
>   - It’s also important to recognize that anything posted to our site is licensed under the Creative Commons license.

#### Addressing content ownership and plagiarism

I added content to two sections to address this. In the "Quality" section, I added a new statement about post ownership:

> - Articles must be the original work of the author posting them, or - in the case of multiple authors - the poster must be one of the primary authors.

And in the Code of Conduct section, I added an explicit mention of plagiarism:

> - Plagiarized Articles will be removed and may lead to moderator action.

#### Clarifying statement about reposting content from elsewhere on Stack Overflow

Your question currently quotes this bullet in the Code of Conduct section as being the crux of your question:

> - Articles should not be exact duplicates of existing Q&As or articles.

As noted, I discussed this with Philippe and the intention here was to only prohibit duplicates within SO, not from outside the platform. We definitely encourage the content to be unique (and that's explicitly noted in other sections of this document), but it would be difficult to require it - our posts are licensed as Creative Commons, which specifically allows reuse.

To clarify the intention of this bullet, I've rewritten it:

> - Articles should not be exact duplicates of existing Q&As or Articles on Stack Overflow.

---

The changes above are live. If you see any additional improvements or clarifications that can be made to these specific concerns, please let me know in the comments. If there are other concerns about this article unrelated to this, please ask a new question about more generally improving this Help center post.

This guidance was automatically updated for Collectives customer-facing documentation when I updated the Help center, so there's parity between the two.

Thank you for bringing this point of confusion to our attention so that we could clarify the documentation. Also, we appreciate you identifying the plagiarised Article so that the moderators could act to remove it. Plagiarism is not acceptable on our platform and we appreciate the work the mods are doing in conjunction with community members relating to identifying and removing plagiarised content.

Comment: Your work in clarifying intent and bringing this to a close is appreciated here.  Thanks for taking point.

Comment: So we're completely fine with people re-posting their old blog posts as Articles in order to gain rep?

Comment: @Joundill I can understand your concerns but there's no indication that's actually happening right now. If people start posting old content (particularly in bulk) we can address those concerns but all of the Articles in your question were posted very closely in time to when the original post was created, so I'm not really sure if it's something we need to address immediately. The oldest original was from October 2021 and the Article was posted 8 months ago... which is essentially the same time.

Comment: So it's allowed for the time being, and not a problem until it's a problem?

Comment: What weird (and wrong) "guidance" that a proper noun used in its proper-noun context as the name of a specific product would not be capitalized. It is *especially* problematic when the name of the specific product also happens to be a noun in everyday usage. The linked guidance needs to be changed, both because it's grammatically incorrect and because it's actively misleading/harmful. In fact, it isn't even internally consistent. The first bullet point is correct; the derivations from it are not. Also, and not coincidentally, "Internet" is always capitalized, since it is a proper noun.

Comment: And, while these changes certainly do improve the guidance, they do nothing to address the elephant in the room, which is that, as noted in the question, "9 of the 18 current Collectives articles are just re-posts of articles posted elsewhere". This pretty conclusively proves that, at least so far, Collectives (see what I did there?) has been a complete failure because it is not adding any value to the site itself or to the Internet at large. If it's just a place to repost stuff that is already available elsewhere, legalities aside, it is not useful. We lose nothing by having mods remove it.

Comment: Thanks, @Catija, the guidance is definitely better now. However, I fully agree with Cody here - it still does not address the elephant in the room that those reposted articles do not provide any value whatsoever since they are "we just post it here too, I guess" blocks of text. If the company wants to convince the community that Collectives have any value, "encouraged" is simply not enough by a long shot. Who's going to encourage posters? Is this stressed to the admins? Or is it just a piece of text nobody will follow since there is no way to enforce them? One simple change would [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] make it enforceable: they should be *required* to be unique pieces of content lest they want to be deleted. And no, the licene is of no concern here, since it does not force the company to keep content that does not adhere to its own guidelines.

Comment: Now that [we see the Collectives tour is literally *recommending* plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418498), touting a major advantage of the new editor as being that it makes it drop-dead easy to copy-paste content that already "exists elsewhere", I think we're getting a better picture of what y'all *really* intend to happen with Articles and/or on Collectives more generally. In light of this, your efforts and attempted reassurances ring extremely hollow. (That elephant just put on a Zoot suit, cranked up the tunes, lit a disco ball, and started dancing in the middle of the room.)

Comment: In regards to the "complete failure" comments, 9/18 copied also means 9/18 new articles, so that is 50% success and added value for the community, could be better but far from a complete failure.

Comment: I don't know about you, @Marijn, but where I come from, when I was in high school and university, completing 50% of the task was considered a "failure". That aside, the fact that 9/18 Articles are *not copied* only means they are not copied, not that they have added value for the community.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine in my country 50% is also a failure but 55% is seen as sufficient, so only two more original articles and the feature will get a passing grade - however, a better comparison might be the questions asked on SO daily, even if less than half of those are good then we don't conclude that SO is a complete failure, only that improvement is possible/needed, but we still appreciate the remaining questions that are good.

Comment: Now if the non-copied articles actually have value is a different question, I just wanted to point out that the feature is not just used for copying, it is also used to provide new information that might be of interest. Therefore it is imo not fully warranted to dismiss the feature completely based on those 50% copied articles.

Comment: @Marijn We haven't really looked at the other 9 articles here closely. Maybe they are suboptimal for other reasons. The most telling thing next to the high self-plagiarism rate is the low total number. 9 actual articles within many months is not much. Almost everyone seems to dismiss the feature currently. And that is even though there are guidelines for articles that seem reasonable to me. It's not that people don't know how articles should be written. They simply don't want to do it.

Answer (score 12):

Paraphrasing what Cody said in [his comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418451/half-the-articles-in-collectives-are-exactly-copied-elsewhere?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment913382_418473), the elephant in the room is that 9 out of 18 **A**rticles are duplicates of content from elsewhere.

It looks like exact duplicates of existing **a**rticles being posted as **A**rticles isn't something unexpected, but is a key feature advertised by SE to prospective Collectives customers in [their Collectives tour](https://stackoverflow.co/collectives/tour/#articles):

[image: Screenshot of collectives tour showing "Copy and Paste" feature]

The orange pop-up captured in the image above contains the text:

> Our editor makes publishing content easy - choose the Markdown or WYSIWYG version. If the content exists elsewhere, simply copy and paste and your formatting comes along for the ride.

Comment: Wow. Just wow. For those who can't read screenshots, there's an orange pop-up (with *horrible* on-hover-only behavior that makes it oh-so-inaccessible) that says: *"Our editor makes publishing content easy - choose the Markdown or WYSIWYG version. If the content exists elsewhere, simply copy and paste and your formatting comes along for the ride."* So, yeah. **Not only are they pushing that absolutely garbage editor, but the major selling point that they've gotten out of it is that it makes plagiarism easier than ever.** I'd say "unbelievable", but... it really isn't anymore.

Comment: @CodyGray the tour mentions easy copying, this is not the same as encouraging plagiarism in case the person posting the Collectives Article is the same person that wrote the copied article. In the examples in the OP here the authors are the same so the guidance so far did not lead to plagiarism, only to easy copying, as intended (except if the original article was already plagiarized).

Comment: @Marijn: Re *"is the same person"*: That is not a guarantee at all. Within a few days, by essentially random sampling (suggesting the plagiarism is rampant), I have seen more than one example of the plagiarism taking place ***at [Medium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_(website))*** and then copied to Stack Overflow. One instance is the [first example listed in this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418451/half-the-articles-in-collectives-are-exactly-copied-elsewhere/418498#comment913446_418451). If it is copied from Medium, DEV, or Quora, it is highly suspect.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I agree that that is a problem, but I don't think you can blame SE for this just because they provide and advertise a copy-paste feature with the legitimate use case of reposting your own articles. Now if this is desirable is another question, maybe not, but you can also argue that this helps to make potentially useful information reach a bigger audience - however the main point is that linking this text from the tour to plagiarism is somewhat one-sided in my opinion.

Comment: "...the elephant in the room is that 9 out of 18 Articles are duplicates of content from elsewhere." And the twin elephant is that there are 18 articles in total or 9 unique ones, for a feature that exists for a year. Not exactly strong growth and indicates that articles is mostly an unused feature.

Comment: @Trilarion I think there's also a zebra or small rhinoceros hiding behind those two elephants. SE has just released Bulletins™ for timely content, this content has already been on-topic for Articles™ over the past year, but nothing of the sort has been posted.

Answer (score 4):

Just concentrating on a small legal aspect that might be of relevance here. Catija's answer also goes into that direction in section "After".

Authors must of course make sure that the content they are going to contribute to Stack Overflow can be published under the current subscriber content license. This includes checking that if said content is already published elsewhere it is not published exclusively there. Depending on the content licenses of the platforms where the content may already have been published (Medium.com, dev.to, ...) that may or may not be the case. If the content was already published exclusively, a verbatim copy would not be possible legally, however a somewhat altered version would probably be fine.

And a general comment: There is not much value in copying 1:1 from somewhere else, although there might be some. If articles are supposed to be useful, they should probably be adapted to the audience here and to the problem they are trying to solve. That would also conveniently avoid any legal problems that might or might not arise.