# Were there options other than deleting this answer?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, moderators, plagiarism

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27737601/1585345), with 251 votes and a ton of useful discussion, was deleted because it contained a table lifted from someone's blog without attribution. That was naughty, but the content and discussion are useful, and the target of links elsewhere on the site, and much more findable than the blog post.

Had the answerer just linked to the blog post, he would have been told off for not writing a full answer. Could this answer not have been preserved, and the lack of attribution corrected?

Comment: Related: *[Answers entirely copied though properly attributed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/answers-entirely-copied-though-properly-attributed/321326#321326)*

Comment: Re *"contained a table lifted from someone's blog"*: It wasn't only the table. The ***entire*** [blog post](https://subhajitsdotnet.wordpress.com/2014/09/21/difference-between-httpclient-and-webclient/) was copied.

Comment: This isn't easy to follow. More than a year after the original answer (2016, revision 3), http://www.diogonunes.com/blog/webclient-vs-httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest/ was added as a reference. This reference was changed about 4 years later to [the source](https://subhajitsdotnet.wordpress.com/2014/09/21/difference-between-httpclient-and-webclient/) for the plagiarised part (2020-10-12, revision 7).

Comment: Google Search returns [two](http://hungphuphat.net/4psqgvs/java-net-http-httpclient-mock.html) other [hits](https://exceptionshub.com/deciding-between-httpclient-and-webclient.html) for the exact phrase ***"please do use the async good­ness with Http­Client that Microsoft pro­vides to the devel­op­ers"***. But they are both broken. Finding out who published first will require more digging.

Comment: The source itself may or may not be plagiarised. https://subhajitsdotnet.wordpress.com/ *seems* to have [plagiarised the sentence](https://subhajitsdotnet.wordpress.com/2014/10/10/living-a-life-for-a-cause-is-called-a-life/) ***"Kailash Satyarthi is my hero because he is courageous and a very hard worker"*** from [this article](https://myhero.com/Kailash_ACS_LB_2008) (by *[MY HERO](https://myhero.com/About)*) published about two months earlier. And plagiarised the rest of that paragraph. In fact, most of the rest of the article, e.g. near ***"His activism started when he was 11 years old."***

Comment: con't - The only original contribution seems to be *"I think that maturity is dealing with every incidents of life in details….."* (compared to the rest, it also stands out with the grammar error, etc.)

Comment: There are a lot of hits on exact phrases, but it is difficult to tell who plagiarises whom. For instance, the exact phrase ***"Inject your code mod­ule into the ASP.NET pipeline. Cleaner and mod­u­lar code."*** is in [this 2019 article](https://dzone.com/articles/a-few-great-ways-to-consume-restful-apis-in-c) (and the rest of the list, including the weird "Caches"), but [the source](https://subhajitsdotnet.wordpress.com/2014/09/21/difference-between-httpclient-and-webclient/) says "Update" (when was it updated?). Is DZone more trustworthy than a random blog article (not a rhetorical question)?

Comment: cont' - The 2019 article references the ***exact*** [same Channel 9 page](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/4-092) (it now redirects to a generic page) as in [the Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27737601/1585345)... (the reference is left out in the blog post). This can't be a coincidence. What was the user name before the account was deleted? Could it [seem at first glance to be self-plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418451/half-the-articles-in-collectives-are-exactly-copied-elsewhere#comment913441_418451) (thus superficially looking legit.)?

Comment: As a note, the entire _question_ seems to be obsolete/not needed anymore, so the remaining value in any of the _answers_ is also thus... suspect at best.

Answer (score 25):

Preserving the answer and correcting the lack of attribution is the responsibility of the answer's *author*, not the business of moderators. Moderators' response to plagiarism is strictly to remove the offending content and warn (or otherwise deal with) the user who posted it.

If your response is: "this is very damaging and potentially destructive", yes; we agree. This is why we have been pushing for better tools to catch plagiarism earlier.

Comment: Presumably, as the post says it was made by "anon" (which isn't a user account) the chance of said author returning to fix and add attribution was *nil* as well?

Comment: Spoken with assurance. And I naively thought we all shared a responsibility for curating a useful site. Since the post was deleted 5 years after it was answered, and the author has long gone, this is just vandalism posing as moderation, no?

Comment: The answer was dissociated from the account that originally posted it, that's why it shows up as "anon". Moderators do that for old, high-scoring plagiarism, as otherwise, deletion wouldn't be enough to remove the illegitimate reputation gain. So, yeah, the chances of the original author returning to fix it are pretty much nil in this particular case.

Comment: A useful site is one that does not contain egregious ethical breaches, like plagiarism. I, too, wish we would catch these sooner, but we work with what we have. You propose that we ignore plagiarism simply because we didn't catch it sooner? I can neither follow nor abide by that logic.

Comment: The message in this answer is somewhat [ambiguous](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/914199). Are you saying it's against the rules for moderators (and/or other users who are not the author) to edit the answer to add attribution? Or are you saying that it's just not the responsibility of other users/mods to do so?

Comment: @CodyGray this is not literature or university exams. As a frequent author of this sort of content, I couldn't care less if you copy it. 5 years too late, the moderator should have added the attribution, or flagged it or something. We are not going to re-have that useful discussion. You should not need 20000 rep to see that answer.

Comment: @bbsimonbb again, it's not the moderator's responsibility to fix content. _"this is not literature or university exams"_ yet plagiarism rules still apply...

Comment: @codygray nowhere do I propose that plagiarism be ignored, but deleting this answer was disproportionate and harmful. Just putting the attribution with a link in the comments, I suggest, would have satisfied everyone. The existing comment fixes the problem. It's a public rebuke for the author of the answer, and the author of the blog will be delighted with a bit of traffic.

Comment: *"Just putting the attribution with a link in the comments, I suggest, would have satisfied everyone."* In no way whatsoever! That doesn't even come close to meeting our minimum requirements for attribution. Comments don't fix any problems, and certainly not a lack of attribution. The attribution is required to be in the body of the answer itself, all copied content must be clearly indicated, the original source must be named, *and* there must be a link back to the original source. None of this is optional or negotiable.

Comment: @codygray that's fine with me, and I'm not the plagiarizer. I shall add the attribution along the lines you suggest and vote to undelete.

Comment: @bbsimonbb Maybe a block quote would be more appropriate to clearly mark the content copied from elsewhere?

Comment: I've updated that answer. I also replaced the `pre/code` table with a MD table, although that apparently doesn't play nice with `>` quote blocks.

Comment: @Cerbrus As I note [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418595/were-there-options-other-than-deleting-this-answer#comment914232_418598), that's still not properly attributed.

Answer (score 7):

If you have the means to fix the current answer, that is add in the missing attribution, and polish all other rough edges at the same time, then by all means please go ahead.

As Cody stated mods don't go fix others' mistakes, as that would be too time consuming, and mods can't be an expert in every field of programming. So they might simply not know what is wrong with the post at all, besides seeing it flagged for plagiarism.

If your edited answer would no-longer have the problems for which it was deleted, plagiarism in this case. You should then flag the post for moderator attention, and make a case for why it should be undeleted, as you can't vote to undelete a mod deleted post yourself.

Comment: This (seems to) directly contradict the first line of Cody's answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus SE strives to be a community resource, while indeed its primarily the authors responsability, if it is clear where the information is take from, why would anyone editing that missing attribution into a good, and highly upvoted answer, be a problem?

Comment: Attribution provided by someone that isn't the author is always just an assumption. As "obvious" as the source might be, you can't be certain which source was quoted, if there's multiple. And that's a rabbit hole I'd suggest we stay out of :D

Comment: It...doesn't. Or, at least, I didn't intend for it to. My point was more what Luuklag said in the second paragraph, that "fixing" plagiarism isn't the work/responsibility of moderators. If someone else wants to post that with proper attribution, then that would be fine.

Comment: How can attribution be an assumption? You mean in cases where something is widely plagiarized multiple places across the Internet, it can be hard to find the original source? Yeah, that's certainly a concern, but not one we worry too much about... If you attribute it to what was *your* original source (i.e., where you got the information), then that's generally sufficient to prove no ill intent. Certainly, for something widely copied, it's appreciated if you or others do a bit of research to find the oldest reference. I don't think that's asking too much.

Comment: I'm not the author of the answer ! And I'm not launching this discussion for myself, since I've enough rep to see deleted answers. If I had any option to fix the problem, I would much rather have done that than show up here.

Comment: @bbsimonbb you do... As these answers explain, you could've added the attribution.

Comment: @cerbus I see that now and shall do so.

Comment: So that was a waste of time then. The post author had added attribution 3 days after the post was deleted in 2020 (not very well). I edited to make the attribution consistent with the guidelines as stated by @CodyGray above. On saving, I learn that the post can't be undeleted, because deleted by a moderator. There was also a message saying 19 more votes.

Comment: @bbsimonbb as I mentioned in my answer, you can't vote to undelete anything deleted by a moderator. Flag for moderator attention, and state your case. Including a reference to this discussion would be helpful.

Comment: @bbsimonbb The post, as of its [current state](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27737601/9), *still* isn't properly attributed, per https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing.  It's not at all clear which parts are copied (hint: it's [not just the table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418595/were-there-options-other-than-deleting-this-answer#comment914231_418595)).  The link to the source is quote-formatted, rather than the quote itself, and it's just in the middle of the plagiarized content.

Comment: Can the content of that off-site resource even be copied onto [so]? As far as I can see, there is no licence on the site, meaning that no one other than the author of the *original* content has the right to re-licence it under CC-BY-SA.

Comment: @Larnu you can always quote someone, there doesn't need to be a license for that, as long as you use propper atribution, and distinguish it as a quote by its formatting.

Comment: That isn't what this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348731/2029983) states, @Luuklag . Copying requires permission. Quoting someone's statement "John Smith stated in their {linked article} 'The best practice in my opinion is xyz'" but quoting the entire source is a *very* different matter to quoting a sentence.

Comment: @RyanM the table can't be quote-formatted, though. SE's MD doesn't seem to like nesting a table in quote formatting.

Comment: *"the table can't be quote-formatted"* I had no problem putting the table in a quote block, @Cerbrus .

Comment: @Larnu PEBCAK on my side, then, it seems o.O

Comment: You need to prefix *every* line of the markdown table with a `> `, as an FYI, @Cerbrus .