# Collectives: Overview of features and community management

Tags: discussion, collectives

*Note for context: this post is part of a series about Collectives on Stack Overflow.  To read the full series, begin at [this primary post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422971/).*

In this post, we’ll be:

- Doing a brief review of Collectives features.
- Detailing updates to articles that will arrive with the next release.
- Outlining how the initial groups of subject matter experts will collaborate and what they’ll focus on as the collectives are formed and launched.

### Feature overview

Features specific to a collective are:

- **The Recognized Member (RM) user role** – A collective Member with additional permissioning to recommend answers and review articles.
- **Recommended answers** – Answers that Recognized Members choose to designate as being endorsed by the collective.
- **Articles** – Long-form knowledge content that is written by collective Members and reviewed/published by Recognized Members.
- **The Leaderboard** – Ranks collective Members based on reputation earned in the collective’s tags.
- **The Actions For You page** – Lists areas where Recognized Members might focus their efforts, such as articles that need review, questions without answers, and top-viewed questions that might benefit from answer recommendations.
- **The Admin user role** – In the near term, Admins of these new collectives will be Stack Overflow Community Managers, managing user permissions and other settings.
- **Bulletins** – In these new collectives, we expect to use bulletins to document policies and processes, in addition to the one-way messaging function they perform in provider collectives.

#### Upcoming feature updates to articles

With the release that accompanies the launch of the next two collectives, we’ll begin adding the standard moderation functions to articles, most notably flagging and its associated flows in moderation tools. This will make it possible for anyone in the community to signal to moderators that something about an article should be assessed.

Additionally, collective Members with 2000 or more reputation points will be able to edit articles. Up to this point, editing has only been available to the original author, the collective’s Admins and Recognized Members, and moderators.

This expansion of editing will be added to articles that were previously associated with decommissioned provider collectives. At this time, it will not be added to articles within existing provider collective, though it will be possible to enable on a per-collective basis.

Collective members with less than 2000 reputation points can still provide feedback via public comments and private feedback to the author. These options will remain for articles in all collectives.

### Launching a collective and subject matter experts

As noted [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422971/), two new collectives will take shape over the coming weeks, focused on the R programming language and CI/CD.

We’ll begin inviting network subject matter experts in these two areas of practice to do the foundational collaboration ahead of the launch. We’ve selected users who've contributed in these tags and subject areas, looking specifically at: overall reputation, amount of posts in the subject areas, scores on those posts, recency of the posts, the number of posts that were answers, and amount of problematic flags.

This collaboration will initially take place on a private Team, to allow for focus, and open ideation. Stack Overflow mods, as well as mods from topic-relevant Stack Exchange communities, will be invited to participate in that pre-launch space as well, to help the collective take shape in a way that does not negatively affect the systems and processes that keep the network running smoothly.

We imagine these subject matter experts as a group that makes consensus-based decisions as they establish the **initial** policies and processes for each collective, keeping community health and content health at the forefront. Their focus will be on the tools and content specific to the collective, defining how the collective does things like:

- Determine how an answer is deemed to be the one that the collective recommends
- Determine how articles (in accordance with the established [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/article-guidelines)) get vetted, published and maintained
- Determine the criteria and process for adding new Recognized Members after the collective launches

Depending on the collective’s topic, there may be other areas of collaboration to explore. Many participants in each pre-launch group will likely become the initial set of Recognized Members for the respective collective. However, participation in the pre-launch group does not oblige someone to become a Recognized Member, nor does it guarantee that they will.

As the individual collectives launch, their respective groups of Recognized Members will shift their conversations to another venue, with the specifics determined by them. They will (if they wish) remain part of the Team, so that they can:

- Offer support to other groups of potential Recognized Members working on pre-launch collaboration for new collectives
- Engage with our research and design teams as we look ahead to further development of collectives

There is much to be defined and determined, and we believe that these new collectives can only succeed if the community takes the lead on those efforts. Community Managers will be involved to start and guide discussions, providing the framework for building out these new spaces.

**What questions do you have about how the new collectives will be launched and guided?**

Comment: I don't like the "The Recognized Member (RM) user role" much. It looks as if not all users are equal anymore and some users worth more than others. I would probably prefer not to see recommendations by someone I didn't choose, if that would be possible, because I would trust the votes by ordinary users more. So if these recommendations and badges could be made optional and I could choose not to see them, all for it.

Comment: @user In answers I try to be more thorough, so it would mean more work and time which I don't want to spend right now. Anyone could say something similar in an answer, if he/she feels like. I don't mind.

Comment: VLAZ's answer more or less covers that topic if I'm understanding what you're saying correctly, though more broadly. Effectively you feel that what the CM's decide is a good metric for users who should be able to recognize a given post or should be given the "recognized member" notice may not align with your own criteria for what makes good, useful, worthy of being recognized posts. There's certainly some very high rep users in tags I follow that post very low quality content often. Would they naturally be great candidates for the (RM) role because they have 500k+ rep?

Comment: @KevinB To be clear, we're choosing a group of users to do this initial collaboration and brainstorming. We have to find this group somehow, and so we looked at various factors that could surface some good candidates. Ultimately it will be that group that works out how to best choose RMs going forward. That may be different for each collective, based on whatever factors make the most sense. This isn't CMs beknighting people for all time.

Comment: The thing I didn't like about sponsored collectives was that when the sponsorship wasn't renewed, the index of Articles disappeared. It was said that individual Articles could be rediscovered as a result of searches, but searching isn't always the best way to get information about a topic. If one of the new collectives isn't directly tied to a revenue stream, what will determine the lifetime of its index of Articles?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Those articles haven't completely disappeared. They can still be recovered through search results, as you mentioned, or they can be found on this page (full index list of all articles on SO): https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/articles. For collectives that are not tied to a specific sponsor, we expect those will exist indefinitely, so the article association would remain. We'll be looking at how to improve article indexing in general.

Comment: So the "The Actions For You page" is like "Review queues" but filtered for the collective's tags. That may cannibalize those who are reviewing away towards collectives.

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer The page is more like specific search queries than review queues. But it's a similar approach. Rather than cannibalize, one thing we'd like to explore is if the Actions For You page (or a similar "dashboard" style approach) might be able to drive *more* people to review queues with a focus on their areas/tags of expertise.

Answer (score 17):

> We imagine these subject matter experts as a group that makes consensus-based decisions

What if consensus is hard to reach?

This is a very important question for me, for as you point out:

> We’ve selected users who've contributed in these tags and subject areas, looking specifically at: overall reputation, amount of posts in the subject areas, scores on those posts, recency of the posts, the number of posts that were answers, and amount of problematic flags.

And yet there is often friction in terms of *values* contributors stand for. Some lean more towards curating content, others toward just answering every question that shows up. The metrics listed seem to favour the latter group*. Although, there certainly are also a lot of curation-minded users who can fit within the criteria.

Something we *desperately* lack is good system of collecting, revising, and discussing canonical duplicates. And a very real problem we see *often* is experts disagreeing on what a duplicate is or is not - leading to close/reopen wars (or at least very brief bouts of such). What happens when these users are sat together and told to reach a consensus?

---

* Except maybe the "problematic flags", as I do not understand what this is. Flags *on contributions* from these users? Or flags *these users have raised*? And "problematic" in what case? If "flag raised" then is it "flags that were ultimately declined" or "flags that were helpful (because they found a real problem)"?

Comment: The friction, debate and (hopefully) eventual consensus is part of the process, right? We're certainly interested to see how the groups work together and we'll be guiding the conversations where needed. These processes (curating, answering) are happening already, so the idea is that if some/many of those people have more visibility into one another's activity, and can even connect/collaborate in some way, the processes will work even better. Less close/reopen wars, more understanding of the shared goals.

Comment: "Amount of problematic flags" is a bit of a catch-all term, and we're looking at flags for behavior (spam/abuse), in addition to suspensions. Essentially focusing on users who are "in good standing".

Answer (score 17):

My main concern here is that you're essentially creating a type of user that is more special than others, and so far there are no formal rules on how those users will be selected. This adds a source of conflict as people are likely to disagree on who exactly should be a recognized member or not. This approach breaks the existing customs on how community moderation works on Stack Overflow. Until now you get the community moderation privileges by reputation and you can get diamond moderator abilities by getting elected. This adds a third way with a so far undefined decision process.

Collectives don't feel well integrated into the community moderation of Stack Overflow, they're more like a parallel society. Which makes some sense when they are sponsored, but is really weird for community-run Collectives.

It makes sense to leave the subject-specific aspects to the initial experts, but I don't think you should start community-run Collectives without global rules around them. You are creating lots of individual mini-sites with different rules here, fragmenting community moderation. And you are hiding the process in a private Team instance, so most of the community cannot see what happens.

Comment: the private team aspect of this really highlights the issue I have with it, that collectives gets billed as this thing that allows collaboration, and yet we need to resort to teams to allow collaboration to occur.

Comment: Recognized Members are not moderators, I want to be clear about that. They are "curators" if you want to pick a term, though that one is much less defined here. RMs have oversight on articles within the collective, but those articles are subject to the same moderation approach as Q&A and adhere to guidelines that were established by the community. Global rules *may* evolve out of this, but I suspect you'd also be unhappy if Stack Overflow was unilaterally dictating those global rules at this stage. We want to let these groups explore what works and share ideas with one another.

Comment: We're looking to the community members within these collectives to help define the rules and evolve them over time. Yes, this initial collaboration is happening on a Team, but that is for reasons of focus, not secrecy. The output will be public. One of the first discussions with each group will be about where the planning and collaboration will happen in the long term. And FWIW there’s clear notices on the Team that all conversations should be conducted with the assumption that they may eventually be shared with the broader community.

Comment: The only collective articles I personally have seen have been plagiarized.  I don't have high hopes for any content submitted to a collective.

Answer (score 13):

What purpose do articles have if they can't be used as duplicate targets for questions? Is that a feature we could expect to see in the future?

All we have thus far are articles that are re-posted from other, better, platforms for that kind of content. Are we expecting articles in these new sponsor-less collectives to function similarly? Will articles always be tied to a single person earning all the credit for a given article rather than allowing it to be a collaborative effort similar to community wikis? We're almost 2 years in on collective articles and I still don't think we have a solid grasp on what purpose they serve for the Q&A platform.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "duplicate targets for questions?" Is it a feature request for the ability to close questions as duplicates of articles? Let us know and from here, we'll be better equipped to provide a response and/or track this as feedback.

Comment: One of the purposes of Articles is to provide long-form knowledge content. We've posted [previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408602/the-user-research-behind-collectives-on-stack-overflow) about the research behind the addition of a long-form content format, specifically under the section "Key findings: Articles". We're interested to learn more about how the community uses articles outside the context of a provider collective, and that will inform any future updates or changes to how they work. For now, they will continue to follow the established reputation conventions of Q&A.

Comment: it was more or less an example, for how articles could be made useful for the purpose people come to SO. If there's an article up there for "Getting started with R" and a new question is asked that directly answered in that article, are we expected to just post answers and reference the article? What purpose does the article serve in these scenarios. If the important bit in the article was instead a canonical Q&A pair it'd be more useful in this scenario with the current design.

Comment: Effectively, to me I see no value in articles for improving the Q&A product. They sit entirely outside of it.

Comment: It's exactly these kinds of questions (like your "Getting started with R" example) that we want to dive into and explore with the people most active in the tags. For example, the R tag wiki is pretty great already -- maybe articles are a way to surface that content better (and maybe in more manageable pieces). Tag wikis are  a long-form content type that already exists, though perhaps some of the people who would most benefit from that content don't ever find it. Think of articles as existing alongside Q&A, complementing it, rather than a method to improve it.

Answer (score 3):

Why do we need a special **recognized member** role? Why is there a need for them to be chosen by a select group of community members? Is the hope that you can onboard subject matter experts that are not yet active on StackOverflow but recognized as reputable. Otherwise you could just make it tag reputation based.

If that role is neither based on reputation nor on public elections it will be a hard sell to the existing SO community.

Comment: Recognized Members are those who can recommend answers and approve articles proposed by non-Recognized Members. As for the *why*, it's devised as a means to drive engagement. Note that I'm not making any statement to whether it actually succeeds at that. With that said, I *fully* agree that coopting the initial pool of RMs sort of contradicts the very definition of these Collectives: "Community-led". Thought it's unclear to me how practical the alternatives would be. As a partial remedy, the RMs are supposed to transparently define how new RMs are added to the group.

Comment: I think it's *likely* that the role would be granted based on reputation or elections, but we wanted to have existing subject matter experts (going by rep and activity level) in the tags to discuss what would work best and see if there are other ideas to consider. The purpose of the role is indeed to drive engagement with a focus on content quality, and to provide an opportunity to do more for those who are looking for such an opportunity. We're interested to see how it works in practice with the non-provider collectives.