# Should the recognized member flair on answers stay when someone leaves a collective?

Tags: discussion, collectives

With the recent events, I've decided to leave the CI/CD collective, thus resigning from the "Recognized Member" position.

It's been brought to my attention that the "Recognized Member" line is still present on my answers anyway:

[image]

I guess this is because the post history records the answer as being posted by a recognized member at time of writing:

[image]

This sounds wrong to me. If someone is not a recognized member anymore, regardless of the reason, their answers should not be flagged as posted by a recognized member (even more when not part of the collective at all).

For reference, my answers on *[DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/tour)* doesn't show a diamond since 2019, so this difference of behavior sounds wrong to me.

What are your thoughts about it?

Comment: Personally, I think it's fair to still show the recognized member at that time. On the other hand, I'm now wondering why the mod diamond is shown on the post's flair on the main site, because it doesn't give any meaning, or even sometimes makes an issue instead...

Comment: Can only agree, maybe I should have linked a related question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424384/3627607

Comment: @AndrewT.: I think it's just a matter of the features/labels having been implemented  differently at different times by different teams. But I agree that it'd be nice to be able to tell that a user was a mod/staff member at the time they posted something in an official capacity, rather than simply displaying the Mod/Staff label on all the user's posts but only while they're currently in that position. (In contrast, Reddit lets you choose whether to distinguish your post as mod- or admin- created on a post-by-post basis, and those labels are kept even if you're no longer in that position.)

Comment: Agree as well, on answers on main site I think the mod status has no added value. On comments, it may depend and having the choice would be good. On meta, mods status sounds indeed 'normal' to have, but here as well someone should be able to voice something as any other user rather than having the ghost of the diamond weighting on it. (My 2cts)

Comment: @V2Blast In addition, the diamond is *very* important for moderation actions. It looks ... strange when one normal user closed/deleted something unilaterally.

Comment: @V2Blast not that I am happy with Reddit right now, but their implementation/design is superior.

Answer (score 14):

I don't think they should.

Instead, if we want the answer to remain "recognized" it should transition to the non-user-based form of recognized answer so that we aren't misinforming visitors on the "recognized" status of the given user. There could be many reasons why a given user might lose their recognized status, not just resignation, so it's probably important for this to have a default result that honors the removal of recognized status.