# Collective Overview page update

Tags: discussion, collectives, announcement

Today, [collectives](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/) got some design updates, notably an updated layout for the header and menu. Also included in these updates is a redesigned Overview page, which changes that initial landing page into more of a “hub” for the collective’s content, grouping questions in different ways. A “Get started” checklist also helps new members and visitors learn more about the features and benefits of a collective. The header and sidebar display various metrics to showcase collective activity to the community.

The Overview page also helps draw attention to more unique and actionable lists of questions in the collective’s tags, such as bountied questions (“Looking for some extra reputation?”), unanswered questions (“Can you answer these questions?“), and questions with recommended answers. A dedicated Questions page has been added to the menu, which includes a more straightforward, sortable list of questions that was formerly on the Overview page.

**If you are a Member of a collective, or someone interested in the collective’s subject area, will you find the updated overview page useful?**

**What additional elements would you like to see?**

[image: Image of the updated Overview page in the example "Audio" collective, showing the updated elements described in this post]

Comment: And what is that audio collective? It’s not on [the list](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives-all). So only paid collectives are active. So where’s the usefulness for the community?

Comment: In all honesty, the collectives hamper my ability to curate the site. Let me cite myself from the chat, [1,5 hours ago](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56290437#56290437): "The «part of <MS> collective» automatically discourages me from curating those Q/As. _Oh, MS sponsored: I’m out._" and "I get the impression that it’s pre-approved by SE, so there’s nothing meaningful I can do". I'm not sure if that's the intention, but it most surely works that way, at least for me.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship Audio Collective is one of our demo collectives. It's not real and used for testing and mockup purposes so we can avoid showing any personal or proprietary information. Similarly we also use the AudioBubble Collective as well in other mockups.

Comment: @Carog I get that (obvious from the list of questions with Lorem ipsum, too), but that sounds like something that could actually perhaps be of use to the community, compared to the existing collectives, which seem more useful to the commercial companies behind them, instead of the SO community.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that the board of "recognized members" in the sidebar, potentially promotes harmful behaviour, such as reputation farming. There's a problem with high-reputation users answering obvious duplicates, and off-topic and LQ questions, instead of doing moderation. But this has probably been brought to your attention before, I assume?

Comment: Not exactly a fan of bounties being a part of any update that isn't removing bounties, but otherwise I think it's an improvement.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship Are you concerned about the specific module (board) on the page, or the broader Recognized Member (RM) idea? Defining each collective's criteria for the RM role is an [ongoing process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424222/inviting-new-recognized-members-to-the-r-language-collective) and would ideally screen out the type of users you refer to.

Comment: "Looking for some extra reputation?" - seriously? I don't know if this header was present in the old version of the page, but this is... quite something. Officially encouraging <rep-something> on the overview page? At least say something neutral like "Looking for some extra challenge?"

Comment: or "Looking for ChatGPT answers?" (/s)

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine We agree, thanks for your suggestion, we'll be changing the title of that section in the next sprint.

Comment: @Carog nice, that is appreciated! Despite *de facto* often being that, can't do anything about it as long as bounties exist in the first place, at least we shouldn't encourage the practice of trying to acquire reputation as opposed to the main goal of building *the* library of questions & answers.

Comment: @Berthold Well, the question you linked to, is about R specifically, so that's not exactly capturing the essence, but I'd say it's a combination. Having it so clearly on the site, and celebrating their reputation, is eye-catching, and really makes it seem as if it's all about the reputation, and that there's a game to get to the top. The broader idea, I'd say is rather pointless. Why recognize them as members of the collective? It only reinforces a conception that not every member is equal. When I see a "recognized member" flair, golden text, description, etc, my brain automatically shuts down

Comment: critical thinking. Because, obviously, this member is now approved, right? That's the idea I get. It's an unfair presentation, saying that because something was written by this member, it must necessarily be correct, or be the best and most accurate.

Comment: Also, the "average response rate (in the last 24 hours)" is horrible. It makes it seem like SO is some personal help desk.

Comment: And also, it's not only the "recognized members" sidebar board that gives this impression. It's also that box right above it: "leaderboard position". This makes it so clear that this **is** indeed a **competitive game**. Is this really what you want SO to be?

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship I hear you about needing to hit the right note with the role flair and recognition. It should be more about the content than the user. We’ve already seen that there are wonderful people who do good work in these tags and are eager to collaborate and find other wats to contribute. Finding the right balance in denoting/recognizing them is something we’ll continue to work on, with the community.

Comment: I also understand the purist/altruist motivation for contributing. I enjoy editing wikis because I like improving a knowledge base. At the same time, we have to understand that it is 2023, not 2009. Role attainment and gamification *do* motivate a lot of people, and to keep replenishing the community of contributors we have to tap into that. There is a balance to hit there as well.

Comment: @Berthold I personally understand (although disagree ideologically) that extrinsic motivation is an important factor in maintaining participation levels, however, this can be done without damaging what is supposed to be the primary goal of the platform. Speaking of, is there anything else than reputation earned that is taken into account when calculating a given user's position in the leaderboard?

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine It is only reputation earned within the collective's tags, excluding bounties.

Comment: @Berthold You already have reputation for recognizing them, don't you? So what's the point in introducing another means of recognizing them? Does it really matter which collective you contribute to? Shouldn't all SO members be attributed for their work, irrespective of which collective they contributed to? The result is that if I split my efforts between 2 collectives, it'll seem like I'm less valued than one that gives 100% to one collective. Can't you invest resources in fixing the reputation system instead of this?

Comment: @Berthold I may have misunderstood, but isn't being a recognized member all about reputation? What about those of us that don't go reputation hunting, but instead make other valuable contributions (anti-AI, anti-plagiarism, duplicate-finding, quality assurance)? We're not awarded any reputation for any of the things we do. Just 3 days ago, a 300k user told me I'm useless to this site, because I don't have more reputation than 1,5k. That same user has a total of 20 helpful flags, while polluting the site with duplicate content, and upvoting such. He even prevented cleanup actions after I'd

Comment: found a perfectly fine duplicate. Is this what you want to encourage? Is this what you value?

Comment: @Berthold thanks for clarifying! Would've been better if it was calculated as a function of useful actions & votes instead, but that's outside the scope of this discussion, of course.

Comment: @ both Oleg & Andreas - excellent points about how reputation does not do enough to reward valuable actions. This is something we talk about a lot internally (not specific to collectives) and there's also a [great discussion on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387356/the-stack-exchange-reputation-system-whats-working-whats-not) about rep (in case you haven't seen it). Collectives is potentially a space to explore new ideas in this space, with the focus on a subset of tags. We're very open to ideas on how to experiment with that. The criteria for being an RM is one approach.