# Collectives: How did we select the initial collective topics for launch?

Tags: discussion, collectives

*Note for context: this post is part of a series about Collectives on Stack Overflow.  To read the full series, begin at [this primary post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422971/).*

As announced [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422971/), there will be two new collectives launching in the coming weeks, focused on:

- R – a programming language
- CI/CD – a methodology

Many of you may be curious about how we arrived at these two topics, and what will factor into the selection of future collective topics. We’re happy to provide an overview of the factors that went into these selections.

#### Testing hypotheses and learning what works

A collective brings developers together in a more focused space, to collaborate and learn from one another, as well as connect with other subject matter experts from the community. Before selecting topics, we determined that would be focused on **areas of practice** rather than a specific organization’s suite of products. An area of practice is, broadly, a set of knowledge and skills that are learned and added to someone’s capabilities. User and audience research revealed that general areas of practice with high potential were: programming languages, methodologies, and disciplines.

As we looked at the other inputs listed below, we also kept a few key questions in mind:

- Is there enough value in the collective to the community without direct participation from a provider?
- Will Stack Overflow’s practices and guidelines create the foundation for healthy collectives?
- Can we appropriately define the areas of focus to create a repeatable and scalable product?

We hypothesize that the answer to all of these questions is “yes”, and selected topics that would help us validate that.

#### Growth rate and engagement levels

To aim for the best possible outcome with this initial set of collectives, it was important to focus on subject areas that are currently “on the rise,” with increasing amounts of questions, answers, and traffic across the community. We also looked for high (or steadily increasing) levels of contributor engagement, since that is essential for maintaining content quality. And we looked for spaces with established best practices that allow subject matter experts to emerge. This would help ensure that the collective can remain relevant in the long term.

#### Content volume and definition

Similarly, there needed to be a “critical mass” of existing content to serve as the foundation, and to ensure that enough subject matter experts were already contributing. The chosen tags needed to clearly define an area of practice, where users at various stages of the learning journey could come together. The topics should be able to fit into statements such as “I am just starting to learn about…” and “I am an expert in…” or “I am continuing to learn about...” This would help ensure that the collective was relevant to enough people’s day-to-day work in the area of practice at various points in their technical journeys.

#### Feedback from subject matter experts on staff at Stack Overflow

There’s no substitute for validation from human minds, even when data is encouraging. We conferred with our colleagues who work in these areas of practice to affirm that these collectives would be appealing spaces to learners and practitioners and could be functional subcommunities. We also wanted to explore subjects that could draw on expertise from the broader Stack Exchange network, since the narrower focus of a collective has similarities to how Stack Exchange sites are defined.

#### Sponsorship potential

As detailed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422973/), sponsorship is how we plan to monetize Collectives. While we’re still exploring what specific forms that might take, and when that might occur, we made a point to choose subject areas that would be of interest to potential sponsors who want to reach developers with a specific focus and explore ways to engage with the community for mutual benefit.

### The road ahead

So what does this mean for the **next** group of collectives that we’ll launch? There are other areas of practice that have appeal based on the criteria detailed above. Those choices will be informed, to a large degree, by what we observe with this first group. In addition to looking at quantitative measurements like user activity and traffic, we’ll be asking qualitative questions like:

- What is the right size for a collective?
- What types of people engage more (or less) within this structure?
- Does it function similar to a guild, where both learners and subject matter experts find value and utility in the space?

We know that the user community will help us further define what makes a collective become a valuable resource and venue for professional development. We expect successes and challenges and will learn from all of it, scaling best practices and topics that benefit the community based on our findings. As we launch these, we’ll return to the community to share findings against the hypotheses and our views on the next steps for Collectives.

Comment: Not completely clear what Feedback (if any...?) you are looking for from this Thread/Announcement...(?) // I find the Terminology used a bit confusing/not completely clear...: "*Topic(s)*" (Definition needed...?) = "*Collective(s)*"? = "*Subject(s)*"? = "*Subject Area(s)*"? = "*Area(s) of Expertise*"? // "*Disciplines*" => What do you mean?, what is that...? (=> Example(s) maybe...?) // "*Methodologies*" => Could also give a few Examples...?, (not sure those are even "On-Topic" for SO anyway...)

Comment: Interesting choice. The R tag has evolved into a homework tag (just state the requirements and some input and the solution, with full source code, will be provided, no questions asked).

Comment: Quoting [Dalija's comment on the main post](/posts/comments/945509): "_CI/CD - this sounds like a magnet for off-topic content that belongs on devops.stackexchange.com_"

Comment: "[...] sponsorship is how we plan to monetize Collectives. [We’re] still exploring what specific forms that might take [...]" - here's a novel monetization idea inspired by the meta response to these announcements and Collectives in general: you could probably get people to pay for _not_ introducing collectives in their favourite tags. Imagine a kickstarter-like model with a funding goal and deadline. Anyone can pay into the pot, if the goal is not reached by the deadline, money is refunded and the Collective is unleashed. Paying suckers could get a badge or hat for their troubles.

Comment: Exactly what @chivracq wrote: I have no clue what you are talking about. What do you mean by "methodologies" and "disciplines" in this sentece? *User and audience research revealed that general areas of practice with high potential were: programming languages, **methodologies**, and **disciplines**.*

Comment: The use of *validate* here sounds like you are biased. Why not use *test* which is more neutral as to the outcome one expects? You seem to know you want collectives so you are finding ways to argue that they will be successful. Top down management? Sentence referred to: *We hypothesize that the answer to all of these questions is “yes”, and selected topics that would help us validate that.*
There's a reason it's called hypothesis testing and not hypothesis validation...

Answer (score 0):

This is a placeholder answer to prevent this staff post from being automatically deleted.

Please remove it if there are ever any actual answers to this question.