# This Collectives Article is a copy of this answer

Tags: support, collectives, articles

[This Collectives Article](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/73064279/how-to-export-large-file-from-google-bigquery) is a copy of [the same user's 2019 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58135134/6632744) to a SO question. It was approved by a Google Cloud recognised member.

This goes against [this rule](https://stackoverflow.com/help/article-guidelines):

> - Articles should not be exact duplicates of existing Q&As or Articles on Stack Overflow.

This issue was briefly discussed [in a comment by Catija](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418451/half-the-articles-in-collectives-are-exactly-copied-elsewhere#comment913329_418473) on a previous question of mine about plagiarism in Collectives Articles.

We need to be able to flag articles, this one was posted by a user with significant reputation, reviewed and approved by another user who has significant reputation and recognition from the Google Cloud Collective, and is still in violation of the rules.

Comment: FWIW, the query at the top which wasn't copied from the original answer was copied instead from [Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements)

Comment: [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/72748632/how-to-resize-gke-pvc-disk) suffers from a similar problem - it's copied [from Medium](https://medium.com/@harsh.manvar111/resizing-pvc-disk-in-gke-c5b882c90f7b), though the author of both seems to be the same person. Not sure if the plagiarization rules apply in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not a clear violation, @Cristik; [the Help Center](//stackoverflow.com/help/article-guidelines) says: "Reposting your own content from elsewhere on the internet is allowed, provided it meets the other guidelines." Although the author did fail to do what they're "encouraged" to do, which is to link back to the original. On a semi-related note, it seems to me that several new(-ish) staff members have a very different (non-existent?) understanding of our long-standing plagiarism policy, resulting in it always lacking from Articles, and now possibly bleeding over into Q&A.

Comment: [Half the articles are like that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418451/half-the-articles-in-collectives-are-exactly-copied-elsewhere) @Cristik The response from SE is that it's okay, and the Collectives tour encourages copy-pasting content from elsewhere :/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks for the report; I've deleted the article that violates the rule.

I agree that it would be useful to be able to flag articles, but I would suggest posting that as a separate feature request (if you or someone else hasn't already done so). I'm retagging this to a [support](/questions/tagged/support) request, since that's effectively what it is, pointing out a rule violation and requesting moderator intervention for a single, specific article.

In the future, until the feature to flag an article is added, such things *can* be brought to moderator attention via a flag: just flag any old post and include the link to the article, along with your rationale for flagging, in a custom moderator flag. Note that this is what we already do to flag a user profile (e.g., for an offensive profile picture or "About" section), since those cannot be flagged directly, either.

Comment: Cheers. I think it's important to highlight these things in Meta. The reasons we've been given so far for not having moderation tools have been that it's essentially not a problem yet, and SE aren't interested in fixing Collectives if they ain't broke. It seems silly to me that I can't flag posts to the Collectives' own moderator team, or to the SO community.

Comment: Plenty of things about Collectives seem silly to me. This, at least, is something that is trivially fixable.

Comment: The user has since deleted their their answer, does that change anything?

Comment: Yes, @KevinB; it seems that the answer needs to be undeleted, because we don't allow users to sabotage useful content, even when they're the ones who originally posted it. The user can, of course, request that that post be dissociated from their account if they no longer want it to be attributed to them, per their rights under CC by-SA.

Answer (score -2):

One point made here is that we need flags for Articles. One reason they don't exist yet is that (as Joundill said) the Collective admins need to be part of that process/workflow. This is a significant change which requires a fair amount of design, development and review with all parties involved in the process. It is needed, but has not happened yet.

Comment: Why would you make Collective admins part of that process? It's already been *clearly* demonstrated that these people have no idea about the type of moderation that we do on Stack Overflow, and they have no desire to maintain the quality of content that this site's members seek to maintain. They are the *last* people I would want to have *any* part in this process. We have elected moderators; they're the ones who should be moderating content on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The other half of my point was that we also can't flag Articles to be handled by the community