# Collectives Update: Intel and looking ahead

Tags: discussion, collectives, announcement

The Intel Collective will be decommissioned on November 17. We are grateful to the team at Intel for helping us explore, in this beta stage, how a Collective can cover a broad range of technologies. We were able to evaluate how Q&A activity for different segments of their product suite changed due to release cycles and other external factors. This has contributed to the future vision for the Collectives concept.

- If you’ve been a member of the Intel Collective, what did you find valuable about the experience?
- Whether reading or contributing, how was the experience of having information about all Intel-related technologies grouped together?

In the coming months, we’ll be launching two new sponsored Collectives. Sponsored Collectives have helped us learn about the value Collectives can bring to the site and to community members with specific areas of expertise and interest. We’re also looking forward to launching some community-led Collectives soon, and we’ll be talking more about the collaborative approach to shaping that concept and ensuring it adds value to the Stack Overflow experience.

Answer (score 26):

> Whether reading or contributing, how was the experience of having information about all Intel-related technologies grouped together?

Let's see...

- None of the [listed articles](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/intel?tab=articles) [(Web Archive link)](http://web.archive.org/web/20221009124416/https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/intel?tab=articles) cracked 1K views
- The collective [somehow absorbed the AMD64 specification into it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412812/1079354) which is just *hilariously* wrong

  - Oh, it pulled a few more into it that weren't related to x86, which is...uh..."what are you doing"-levels of confusing
- There was a lot of noise about [how they were posting advertisements disguised as tutorials - advertorials](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412833/1079354), for which the behavior went unchecked
- Oh, and the articles [were reposted in other places as well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418451/1079354).

To that last point, Catija's points are well-received by me.  I respect the balance being struck in this context.  There's no value in duplicating something on the platform itself.

But this *does* speak to a litmus test of the health or viability of a product; if the intent of it is to be used as a place to aggregate this kind of information into one place, then on its face, having it replicated in other places independent of each other undermines the intent of the service entirely.

I'm really hoping y'all get this Collectives thing figured out such that it brings value for those who pay for it (companies) and the community at large.  The fact that this is the approach the company has elected to take keep the lights on has me all kinds of antsy at this point.

Comment: There isn't any notification badge or something similar to notify collective members about new articles in a collective. Only the first 1-2 articles have most view that too were posted when collectives were first introduced so I assume users were just checking around the new articles functionality or the post was featured on meta for some reason.

Comment: I also believe that when we have community-led collectives, we'll see a better set of uses for articles and less of the behaviors that were problematic in some early articles (spammy, reposted content, for instance).    @Dharmaraj the point about the lack of notification for new article content is real, no question.

Comment: @Makoto, I also think it's important to remember that collectives are not "the approach that the company is using to keep the light on".  Collectives and the revenue derived from sponsorship of them are a part of a healthy and well-balanced approach to revenue for us.  We derive revenue from the advertising business still, and employer branding, and from Stack Overflow for Teams.  While there's no doubt that Collectives represent a terrific potential for income, it's not an "all the eggs in one basket" kind of situation.

Answer (score 2):

I've been not very frequent user of SO recently, so just noticed the disappearance.

Well I don't care much.

I cared more about the technologies provided by Intel and their competitors: the [x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86) CPUs, and their features. The collective articles were focused on other Intel products. Though the collective still encouraged good answers on x86 technology. This was odd.

I questioned "government" of Intel on x86 related tags before: [Intel collective owns [x86] and [x86-64]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412812/intel-collective-owns-x86-and-x86-64)